# How can I draw this picture in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

[image]

can somebody help me with this, I tried my best but fail.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{tikz,graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[!tb]
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
%drawing shapes 
\draw [fill=white] (1.5,0.3) rectangle (10,1.0);
\draw [thick] (6,1.5)-- (7,2)--(6.6,2)--(6.6,3.5)--(5.4,3.5)--(5.4,2)--(5,2)--(6,1.5);
\draw [fill=white] (5.4,3.56) rectangle (6.6,3.66);
\draw [fill=white] (5.4,3.7) rectangle (6.6,3.75);
\draw [thick] (1.8,3.9) to [out=180,in=270] (1.5,4.1)--(1.5,5.1) to [out=90,in=180] (1.8,5.3);
\draw [thick] (9.8,3.9) -- (10.5,3.9) --(10.5,5.3) -- (9.8,5.3);




\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: There is no `graphix` package in a standard TeX installation as far as I know. I assume you mean the `graphicx` package (which is not needed to compile your code).

Comment: Can you provide a better question title (as opposed to "how to draw this...")?

Comment: You could just use nodes like `\node at (6,4.6) {Foo}; \node at (5.75,0.65) {Bar};` and place the other things inside.

Comment: May I ask how you got the code that you show? Do you need it to be *excactly* like this? Because the upper part looks like a matrix to me where the left side has a ( and the right side has a ] which is probably easiest to create using the `nicematrix` package. It would also be not too complicated to add the arrow.

Comment: not exactly, i only need to produce what is in the picture.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would probably go with the `nicematrix` package to create the upper matrix and add the rest using Ti*k*Z (note that you might want to add some spacing above and below, since the bounding box is probably a bit off;

```
\documentclass[border=20pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{nicematrix, tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
\(
\begin{NiceArray}{ l *{16}{c} }
\textbf{Dimension:} 
    &  1 &  2 &  3 &  4 &  5 &  6 &  7 &  8 &  9 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 15 & 16 \\
\textbf{Position:} 
    &  0 &  1 &  1 &  0 &  1 &  0 &  0 &  1 &  1 &  0 &  0 &  1 &  0 &  1 &  1 &  0 \\[2cm]
\CodeAfter
    \OverBrace[shorten, yshift=5pt]{1-2}{1-9}{\textbf{First vehicle}}
    \OverBrace[shorten, yshift=5pt]{1-10}{1-17}{\textbf{Second vehicle}}
    \SubMatrix({1-2}{2-17}]
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \coordinate (anchor) at ([shift={(-0.6,-0.35)}]$(2-9)!0.5!(2-10)$);
        \draw (anchor) rectangle ++(1.2,-0.05);
        \draw ([shift={(0,-0.125)}]anchor) rectangle ++(1.2,-0.1);
        \draw ([shift={(0,-0.3)}]anchor) -| ++(1.2,-0.5) 
            -- ++(0.5,0) -- ++(-1.1,-0.75) coordinate (tip)
            -- ++(-1.1,0.75) -- ++(0.5,0) -- cycle;
        \node[draw] at ([shift={(0,-0.5)}]tip) {
            (1,2), (2,1), (3,1), (4,2), (5,1), (6,2), (7,2), (8,1)
        };
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{NiceArray}
\)
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Or you could create it purely with Ti*k*Z and use a `\matrix`:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, matrix, decorations.pathreplacing, calligraphy}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \matrix[matrix of nodes, every node/.style={anchor=base, minimum width={1.5em}}] (m) {
        |[text width={6em}, align=left]| \textbf{Dimension:} 
            &  1 &  2 &  3 &  4 &  5 &  6 &  7 &  8 
            &  9 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 15 & 16 \\
        |[text width={6em}, align=left]|\textbf{Position:} 
            &  0 &  1 &  1 &  0 &  1 &  0 &  0 &  1 
            &  1 &  0 &  0 &  1 &  0 &  1 &  1 &  0 \\
    };

    \draw[decorate, decoration={calligraphic curved parenthesis, mirror}] 
        (m-1-2.north west) -- (m-2-2.south west);
    \draw (m-1-17.north east) -- ++(1.5pt,0) |- 
        (m-2-17.south east -| m-1-17.north east);
    
    \draw[decorate, decoration={calligraphic brace}] 
        ([xshift=2pt]m-1-2.north west) -- ([xshift=-2pt]m-1-9.north east)
        node[midway, above=2pt] {\textbf{First vehicle}};
    \draw[decorate, decoration={calligraphic brace}] 
        ([xshift=2pt]m-1-10.north west) -- ([xshift=-2pt]m-1-17.north east)
        node[midway, above=2pt] {\textbf{Secoond vehicle}};

    \coordinate (anchor) at ([yshift=-2pt]$(m-2-8.south)!0.5!(m-2-9.south)$);
    \draw (anchor) rectangle ++(1.2,-0.05);
    \draw ([shift={(0,-0.125)}]anchor) rectangle ++(1.2,-0.1);
    \draw ([shift={(0,-0.3)}]anchor) -| ++(1.2,-0.5) 
        -- ++(0.5,0) -- ++(-1.1,-0.75) coordinate (tip)
        -- ++(-1.1,0.75) -- ++(0.5,0) -- cycle;
    
    \node[draw] at ([shift={(0,-0.5)}]tip) {
        (1,2), (2,1), (3,1), (4,2), (5,1), (6,2), (7,2), (8,1)
    };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thx, is there any other package similar to "nicematrix", I am facing trouble with it. my latex refuses to install the package

Comment: You could also create the matrix using a Ti*k*Z matrix directly. I'll update my answer in a moment.

Comment: maybe, it is my latex or something else. i use latex 11, and latest miktex. now it is does not find "calc, matrix, decorations.pathreplacing, calligraphy" in its libraries

Comment: @Chamanga You can download these libraries from CTAN (https://ctan.org/pkg/pgf and https://ctan.org/pkg/spath3) and just place them inside your working directory. But actually, these libraries are part of every regular TeX distribution. You might want to update your TeX installation and make sure that the complete Ti*k*Z package and the `spath3` package are installed.

Comment: great,  now everything is working wonderful.